# Internal Definitions without Access to Enclosing Scope

Tags: racket

> Can access to lexical variables be stripped for internal definitions?

Maybe this is a non-problem, but sometimes I wish I could define internal procedures without access to enclosing scope. Consider this example:

```
(define (usual-racket n)
  (define (hi a)
    (displayln n))
  (hi 'hi)
  n)
```

Here I "accidentally" typed `n` instead of `a` in the internally-defined procedure `hi`. Because `n` is visible at the point of definition, racket rightly doesn't complain. Is there some way to make a special form like `define-free` which would drop this enclosing context? I thought using `strip-context` would work but obviously I'm not thinking correctly as this didn't work:

```
(define-syntax (define-free stx)
  (let ((s (strip-context stx)))
    (syntax-case s ()
      ((_ (name args ...) body ...)
       #'(define (name args ...) body ...)))))
```

If I have a new kind of *outer* `define` then it does work:

```
(define-syntax (define/free stx)
  (syntax-case stx (define-free)
    ((_ (N A ...) (define-free (n a ...) b ...) B ...)
     #'(define N
         (let ((n (lambda (a ...) b ...)))
           (lambda (A ...) B ...))))))

(define/free (definitely-works n)
  (define-free (hi a)
    (displayln n)) ; n: unbound identifier in module in: n
  (hi 'hi)
  n)
```

...But I was hoping there was a solution that didn't require redefining the base `define` syntax and trying to manage all the places internal definitions could possibly show their heads.

***Clarification edit***
My motivation is not to solve the problem above, that was just a scope example. My motivation is mostly to manage scope in such a way that helps the reader of my code (mainly: me) understand what sort of place this procedure has within its enclosing scope. Many internal definitions I use are helper procedures to make the body of the code easier to write and understand. Such helpers do not need access to any scope—they might as well be top level definitions. But putting a procedure at the top level, for good or for ill, often suggests that it is there because to understand various procedures you have to keep this procedure's definition in mind. So the "surface" of the module would become larger if such internal definitions were lifted to the top level when written.

Consider fibs:

```
(define (fib n)
  (define (f index n-2 n-1)
    (if (< index 1)
        n-1
        (f (sub1 index) n-1 (+ n-2 n-1))))
  (f n 0 1))
```

The internal procedure `f` is there only to manage the additional state needed to calculate `fib`. It doesn't need any additional context that `fib` may have. It could just be at the top level. But if it were at the top level, the implication—for good or for ill—is that it's used more than once by multiple procedures and that's why it has the top-level scope it has. It's not a problem if it were at the top level—it just shouldn't look like it, because of the way we (or less presumptuously "I") think about scope.

I am reasonably certain that the standard practice is not to put a procedure higher up the scope chain than it needs to be precisely because of this clutter, but in fact scope size only tends to increase, which means at the level of internal definitions (say three levels deep) the reader of the code (me) needs to think about the whole scope this procedure sees, even if the procedure doesn't need it. Wouldn't it be nice to say so? "Ah, this is an `unlocal` block, it has all the information it needs from top-level requires and its own arguments."

Comment: Interesting! First, though, here's a simple question; why don't you just define your inner function (in this case, `hi`) at the top level? I think the answer to this question might help to clarify the details of the device you're looking for.

Comment: @JohnClements Top-level definitions to me make a lot of mental clutter. Code position says something about the code. Top level code is seen by all and could be needed at any time to understand a bit of a procedure. In general you don't have this problem with internal definitions, they can only leak out in a closure. So my question is sort of the reverse of this, to stop things leaking in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really cool and interesting case for why `#%lambda-begin` should exist. (I have been pushing for it for a while.)

Anyway, the way I've dealt with this so far is to instead define the element outside of the function, but inside of the define. Taking the fact example from above:

```
(define fib
  (let ()
    (define (f index n-2 n-1)
      (if (< index 1)
          n-1
          (f (sub1 index) n-1 (+ n-2 n-1))))
    (lambda (n)
      (f n 0 1)))
```

This does still have the issue that you had to type `(define fib ...)` rather than `(define (fib ...) ...)`, but it does make it very clear what you are doing, and its a little more robust than your `define/free` macro.

Another thing you can do is use [`syntax-local-lift-expression`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html?q=syntax-local-lift#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._syntax-local-lift-expression%29%29) to lift the function to the module scope, using the hygiene system to ensure that you can use the same name multiple times.  The overall macro would look something like:

```
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse
                     syntax/parse/lib/function-header
                     racket/syntax))

(define-syntax (define/free stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ f:function-header body ...)
     (define f*
       (syntax-local-lift-expression
        #'(let ()
            (define f body ...)
            f.name)))
     #`(define f.name #,f*)]))
```

Now, `f` has been lifted out of the current context altogether and given a unique name. Then, the original binding of `f` simply maps to the new name of `f`.

Thus, you're `fib` example works:

```
(define (fib n)
  (define/free (f index n-2 n-1)
    (if (< index 1)
        n-1
        (f (sub1 index) n-1 (+ n-2 n-1))))
  (f n 0 1))
```

But if you try to use `n` within `f`, you will get an unbound identifier error:

```
> (define (fib n)
    (define/free (f index n-2 n-1)
      (displayln n)
      (if (< index 1)
          n-1
          (f (sub1 index) n-1 (+ n-2 n-1))))
    (f n 0 1))

n: identifier used out of context
context...:
matching binding...: in: n
```

(You could also catch the error and raise a nicer one with [`raise-syntax-error`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html?q=raise-syntax-error#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._raise-syntax-error%29%29), [`with-handlers`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html?q=with-handlers#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._with-handlers%29%29), and [`exn:fail:syntax?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html?q=exn%3Afail%3Asyntax%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._exn~3afail~3asyntax~3f%29%29), but that is a different question altogether.)

Comment: The final syntax quasiquote needs to be `(define f.name #,f*)`. I'd edit it myself but as a 4-character edit it won't let me. Thanks so much, `syntax-local-lift-expression` hits the spot!